# how to edit a nested model with partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

This is the model:

A Quiz instance that has some Question instances, where each Question instance has some Answers instances

When editing a quiz, how should my controller look like?

My current approach is to have a QuizzesController, and not a QuizController, a QuestionsController and an AnswersController. **Is it enough with just the QuizzesController?**

Lets assume I just use 1 controller, **how should I structure the Edit action?**

```
Edit(int id) //for editing quiz
Edit(int id, int questionId) // for editing a question
Edit(int id, int questionId, int answerId) // for editing an answer
```

alternative is:

```
EditQuiz(int id)
EditQuestion(int id)
EditAnswer(int id)
```

Comment: There's no way to answer this. It's entirely up to you and how you want to design your application. MVC doesn't care which approach you follow and there could be valid arguments for either approach or even something else entirely.

Comment: can you get an answer instance from database with only answer id? or do you also need to provide quiz id and question id ?

Comment: @YuliamChandra yes I can

Comment: I prefer second alternative to make easier when creating anchor link `a href`, I mean shorter and less parameters to send